# Definition of Turing machines and rejection states

Tags: turing-machines

In some definitions of Turing machine, there is only a set of accepting states and no mention of a set of rejecting states.

But it seems to me that the definition that includes only a set of accepting states and that includes also a set of rejecting states will differ.

How can they actually be shown to be equivalent? Or is it not the case?

Answer (score 3):

A deterministic Turing machine accepts if, and only if, it terminates in an accepting state. Any state that is not accepting is rejecting by default.  There are various equivalent ways of defining Turing machines: for example, instead of having a HALT instruction and accepting and rejecting states, you could have explicit ACCEPT and REJECT instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "*equivalent*" you were talking about the language a TM accepts. Then the proof of the two definitions' being equivalent can be made.

On one hand, simply adding a rejecting state to any TM without one does not change what it accepts. On the other hand, removing the rejecting state from a TM with it does not change the language it accepts, too. The word "remove" is a bit tricky, but in fact you can think it as just demoting the rejecting state to a normal state that is not accepting either.

To put it another way, these changes all do not affect the language a TM accepts, because by definition a TM accepts a language or not depends **ONLY** on its accepting states, so any other states, including the rejecting state, are irrelevant to this in some ways.

However, the existence of the rejecting state may play a significant role in several applications, for example, when a TM is used as a subroutine, or when some action needs to be done when a TM halts (e.g. writing YES/NO on the tape).